# Trying to fork a Node.js process using Gulp and Babel on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, gulp, babeljs

My application is built with isomorphic JavaScript, and I'm using a [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) task to run a Node.js server on a new instance, then listening to files change to make a server restart and a browser reload (using [Browsersync](http://www.browsersync.io/)).

I want to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to write my server-side code in ECMAScript 6, as well as my client-side code. I want to avoid the [Babel polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) and use `node_modules/.bin/babel-core.cmd server.js` command instead, but `child_process.fork()` allows only an executable:

```
let child = cp.fork('server.js', [], {
  execPath: path.normalize('node_modules/.bin/babel-node.cmd'),
  env: _.assign({NODE_ENV: 'development'}, process.env)
});
```

This script doesn't work, and as intended, throws the following error:

```
child_process.js:588
  p.open(fd);
    ^
Error: EINVAL, invalid argument
    at Error (native)
    at Object.exports._forkChild (child_process.js:588:5)
    at Function.startup.processChannel (node.js:704:10)
    at startup (node.js:59:15)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I want to use `child_process.fork()` to this case. `child_process.spawn()` doesn't work here because there is not a direct communication between the two Node.js processes, indeed. And I'm listening from events to performs actions:

```
// server.js

server.listen(port, function() {
  if (process.send) {
    process.send('online');
  } else {
    ...
  }
});

// gulpfile.babel.js

child.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.match(/^online$/)) {
    if (browserSyncServer) {
      browserSyncServer.reload();
    }

    if (!started) {
      started = true;

      gulp.watch(config.serverScripts, () => {
        plugins.util.log('Restarting development server.');

        server.kill('SIGTERM');
        server = startup();
      });

      cb();
    }
  }
});
```

Any workaround with this? Or I'm forced to use the Babel polyfill directly on my server-side code?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, did you find a workaround?

Comment: Same problem here. BTW, you can usually use `spawn` with `{stdio : [0,1,2,'ipc']}` to create the communication channel BUT here does not work. I think for the same reason `fork` does nor work.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the command that it uses to spawn the node process with the `execPath` option.

For example, if I want to spawn a node server with `babel-node` instead of `node`, I can type:

```
process.fork('/path/to/server.js', { execPath: "babel-node" }, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

  if (error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }
});
```

Comment: In that case, Nicolas example has a process.send('online') function. Using execPath option makes process.send undefined.

Comment: why does that happen? :\

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem was well. With [this issue](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2519#issuecomment-251946882) I open on mocha I could solve the problem.

> Running `babel-node node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha test.js` applies by default the compiler to the child process and there is no need to set the `execPath`.
>
> **PS:** Once you run the `mocha` with `babel-node` there is no need to pass `--require` or `--compilers`.